# Добавление и дальнейшая работа в SQL, когда один из параметров - Класс

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, классы

Изучаю принципы и сам процесс работы с базами данных (SQL - для начала). Интересен вопрос, что если у меня есть две таблицы **Books** и **Authors**.
И таких же два простых класса для дальнейшего создания экземпляров этого класса..

```java
public class Book {
    private String nameOfBook = "";
    private Author author = null;

    private Data.Genre genre;
    private String description = "";

    public Book(String nameOfBook, Author author, Data.Genre genre, String description) {
        this.nameOfBook = nameOfBook;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.description = description;
    }

    //getters and setter..
}
```

```java
package com.company;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Author {
    private String firstName = "";
    private String lastName = "";
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;


    public Author(String firstName, String lastName, LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    //getters and setter...
}
```

Так вот, у меня есть стандартная, уже подключенная **ДБ**, и две таблицы в ней: **Books** и **Authors**. Проблем с отправкой и получением данных в таблицу новых **Author'ов** - нет, но что насчёт **Books**, так как там один из параметров сам класс **Author**. Надеюсь вы поняли моё скудное объяснение, за что прошу прощения, и сразу благодарю за любой фидбэк.

Приветствую любые вопросы и уточнения )

Comment: Из вопроса не ясно как вы работаете с БД, используете ли ORM или пишете руками SQL запросы? Для начала вам нужно разобраться, какие бывают [типы связей между таблицами](https://habr.com/ru/post/488054/) в БД, а потом уже реализовывать это с учетом того, что у вас в коде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В БД создайте в таблице `Author` (да и в `Book` тоже) поле `id` типа целое, но чтобы оно автоматически генерировалось уникальное, когда при вставке в БД вы это поле не указываете (в mysql это можно сделать добавив ключевое слово `AUTO_INCREMENT` в определение поля, в postgresql задав тип поля `serial`).

Так же нужно добавить это поле в класс `Author`.

Теперь при создании записи в `Author` он будет автоматически получать уникальный идентификатор. В таблицу `Book` создайте поле `author_id` и там храните идентификатор автора (т.е. значение из поля `id` в таблице `Author`). Для этого поля нужно также добавить foreign key ограничение, чтобы БД проверяла, что вы задаете правильное значение для поля (т.е. такое которое существует в `Author`).

При вставке в таблицу `Book`, берите значение `book.getAuthor().getId()`, и его используйте для того, чтоб задать значение в поле `author_id`. При чтении объекта `Book` из БД, либо делайте дополнительный запрос к таблице `Author` по `id` из поля `author_id` и присваивайте полученный таким образом объект `Author` в поле `Book.author`. Так же можно получить поля автора используя join.

Comment: Благодарствую )